# The distorted audio issue if I set low volume

Tags: raspbian, audio

I bought Raspberry Pi 2 model B and tried to play the audio after rpi-update.

- `amixer set PCM 100%; aplay sample.wav`

It is good quality.
However, the audio is gradually distorted when I turn down the volume.

- `amixer set PCM 80%; aplay sample.wav`
- `amixer set PCM 70%; aplay sample.wav`
- `amixer set PCM 60%; aplay sample.wav`
- ...

The following mp3 file is recorded through headphone output: [headphone_output.mp3](http://mouten.info/audio/headphone_output.mp3). (The original audio is available at [freesound.org](http://freesound.org/people/Timbre/sounds/94564/)).

I guess the distortion like a bit-crusher is caused by D-A convertor. Is this a correct behavior?

I want to set low volume without distortion.

Comment: Experiencing the same problem... Any progress?

Comment: I'm still working on this problem. In addition, RPI2's SoC is BCM2836 but lsmod shows the modules named snd_bcm2835. I think this causes the distortion.