# Raspberry Pi 2 low volume on headphone socket

Tags: audio, pi-2

I'm using a Raspberry Pi 2 as an AirPlay receiver connected into an external amp via the headphone socket, and running `shairport-sync`. I am seeing a low volume on the headphone output socket, such that I need to turn the input gain on the amp up far more than any other signal source, and have the RPi's output gain on 100% to be able to get a decent signal. I have eliminated `shairport-sync` as they cause by just using `aplay` and the various samples. So this this is a Pi issue.

Here are some observations:

- When I change the output device between headphones, HDMI and auto using `amixer cset numid=3 N` (where `N` is `0`, `1`, or `2`), the output volume does not alter. I am wondering if it's *always* coming out the HDMI port and I'm just hearing bleedthrough of the audio.
- When I reduce the playback volume using `alsamixer` or `amixer`, not only does the sound get quieter, but I also get distortion, exactly as set out in [this (unanswered) question](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/30192/the-distorted-audio-issue-if-i-set-low-volume).

If left at 100%, apart from being quiet, the sound is of reasonable quality I suppose (I'm guessing it isn't a HiFi DAC).

All the shairport tutorials (which are mainly based on the RPi 1) seem to suggest the volume is too loud at 100% and should be turned down. Is this a common issue? Or is there some hardware-esque setting I can use to fiddle with the gain?